# inserting has_many through record metadata during devise registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

I would like to thank you in advance.
I have been looking around of the internet to get an answer for this but could not find anything so here goes the questions.

I have a user registration process through devise that I have customized the registration looks like so.

```
 <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :name, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>


<div>Teaching:<%= f.label :language_ids %><br />
<%= collection_select('user', 'language_ids', @languages, :id, :name, {}, {:included_blank => false,:multiple => true } ) %>
</div>

<div>Learning:<%= f.label :language_ids %><br />
<%= collection_select('user', 'language_ids', @languages, :id, :name, {}, {:included_blank => false,:multiple => true } ) %>
</div>
```

On my controller currently it looks like this

```
def create
    @languages = Language.all
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    if resource.save
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end
```

Now there is a field that i have to set to toggle the metadata flag on the intermediary table/model called fluency. Basically I need to set it to 0 if the data is coming from the Learning multiselect and a 1 if the data comes from the Teaching multiselect. Currently it's just inserting it without toggling that metadata.

Been looking all over but can't find anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would extract the parameters before you save your resource.  Then, I would wrap the creation of the `Fluency` record and the saving of the `resource` in an `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` block, so that if persisting of any of those records fails, they all roll back.

Something like this:

```
  def create
    @languages = Language.all
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      create_fluency_records(sign_up_params[:fluency_fields]

      result = resource.save!
    end

    if result
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end
```

Note that your form will have to change to pass the "learning" and "teaching" values in a hash called `fluency_fields` within the request parameters.

Comment: Where does the passing of the fluency happened?, I'm not following... Do I have to change the view?

Comment: It comes from the form as nested parameters.  Yes, you'll likely have to change the view a bit.

Comment: Very close now! <%= collection_select('user', 'language_ids', @languages, :id, :name, {}, {:included_blank => false,:multiple => true } ) %> I tried something like so on my view it worked in inserting to the fluency model just I'm not able to change one of it's fields at the same time..